Will a leaf shutter with a smaller diameter than the back of a lens lower it’s f-stop?
I have an old Ektanar 104mm / 2.8 projector lens that I would like to adapt to using in medium format film photography (buying 2.8 MF lenses can be rather expensive, wouldn’t you say?). Problem is the cost of a shutter large enough to cover it’s back completely is rare and expensive.
Coincidentally, I have a computer-rapid shutter with an inner diameter of about 18mm or so when open.
The projector lenses glass on the back is about 30mm or so.
Testing with ground glass reveals that coverage seems to be fine over 6x6cm, but I honestly can’t tell if it’s dimming it - or if the DOF is being increased/altered as well.
Is this the same as reducing the f-#? Or does the f number only refer to the “entrance pupil” whatever that is? I am fine with making the image circle smaller, slightly okay with lowering effective light transmission, and not okay at all with increasing dof (I’d probably just rather get a Mamiya RB67 lens at that point).
Thank you all for reading, peace.

If the open leaf shutter behind the lens is open and visible through the front of the lens as the smallest restriction when the lens' aperture diaphragm is wide open, then the shutter will reduce your lens' maximum f-number. You will also experience a corresponding change in depth of field.
The entrance pupil is determined by the diameter of the opening through the lens as viewed through the front of the lens. This is theoretically measured on the center of the lens' optical axis from a position at infinity, but you can get very close to the same measurement by placing a ruler across the front of the lens and viewing it from as far away as is practical with the open shutter in position behind the lens and the lens' aperture diaphragm wide open. Another way to test is to place the open shutter in position behind the lens and stop the lens down until the lens' aperture diaphragm is smaller than the open shutter and the shutter can no longer be seen from the center of the lens' optical axis. The effective maximum aperture will be a value between the last f-stop when you can see the edges of the open shutter and the next f-stop when you can't see the open shutter.

The f# only refers to the entrance pupil restriction. That is the size of the aperture restriction as seen by the source/subject.
If you shine a light through the back of the lens/aperture restriction you can measure the entrance pupil directly on the objective lens.

@user107063, I deleted that error; I was thinking "two stops slower" but didn't convey it well/correctly.

Measuring the entrance pupil "directly on the objective lens" only works when focusing on infinity and placing a point(!) light source right in the sensor plane.  Only then do the beams of light exit in parallel from the entrance pupil (as viewed from outside: the reality is different, but entrance pupil size does not care about reality).  Also the front lens surface of a reasonably current front lens tends to do a pretty thorough job of not scattering enough light for you to see that circle.  And is sometimes not very plane.

@user107063, and f# (focal length) is only accurate when focused at infinity as well.
